# Sequelize associations don't work, how to fix?

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I've defined two models: `User` and `Bookmark`

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const User = sequelize.define('User', {
    name: DataTypes.STRING,
    email: DataTypes.STRING,
    pass: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {});
  User.associate = function(models) {
    User.hasMany(models.Bookmark)
  };
  return User
};

'use strict'
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Bookmark = sequelize.define('Bookmark', {
    title: DataTypes.STRING,
    url: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {})
  Bookmark.associate = function (models) {
    // Bookmark.belongsTo(models.User)
  }
  return Bookmark
}
```

The `associate` functions get called through the boilerplate code generated in `models/index.js`:

```
Object.keys(db).forEach(modelName => {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db)
  }
})
```

However there are two things not happening that I expect they should:

```
User.findAll()
  .then(users => console.log(typeof users[0].getBookmarks))
```

Above `getBookmarks` is `undefined`.

And secondly, I see no schema updates being propagated to the data base.

I also tried reactivating `// Bookmark.belongsTo(models.User)` from the Bookmark model and nothing changes.

**The problem and the fix**

It turns out you have to explicitly call `sync` on an `Sequelize` instance, and, if the tables in the association are already present, you have to include the argument `{force: true}` for the association to be persisted to the database.

Answer (score 1):

To get the associated `Bookmarks` you missed to `include` `Bookmark` while querying for `User`.

Including `Bookmark` the query should look like following

```
User.findAll({
    include: [
        {
            model: Bookmark
        }      
    ]
}).then( users => {
    // you now get the `users`, with `bookmarks` associated with it.
});
```